Orb brush sculpts a lot of dots instead of a smooth line
I have tried every single setting for this orb cracks smooth edge brush and no matter what I do, it sculpts these weird dots like somehow I am pressing harder (which I'm not).
I tried changing the falloff, the input samples, spacing, stabilize stroke, the strength of the brush. Nothing works really. I am following a tutorial and I can clearly see their brush is working just fine so it's some setting I am missing, but I don't know what it is.



This sounds like "jitter". Maybe the topology has few vertices there too....
Are the scratches done by the same brush?

The mesh is very high poly, it has around 8 million vertices. The scratches are done by the same brush, yes. I checked and jitter is set to 0 and the jitter unit is set to brush, not view.
